# Google Sheets ArrayFormula with Filter and/or SumIf

Tags: filter, google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

I'm working on creating a faster, more efficient report within Google sheets (we're limited to that at the moment, but senior management is looking for alternatives in the distant future). The first version was Queries and Importranges across roughly 3,000 cells. This, of course, caused monumental lag and frequently caused major issues, particularly when looking for different date ranges.

The second version used Importranges to about 30 different tabs within the workbook, then using Filters to get the data from those tabs. It is significantly faster, but still somewhat sluggish; taking up to 5 minutes to update with new date ranges.

The third version, the one I'm working on, I'd like to make using ArrayFormula so that instead of 3,000 cells with a formula, it'll be about 60 cells with formula, which I think should speed things up tremendously.

I've looked at several options, but none seemed to quite fit the need that I'm looking to fill. I even experimented with several to see if they could be tweaked to fit. No dice.

Here's a sample spreadsheet where I've entered a couple of days worth of test data for some sample colleagues:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18rF3ZnvmNKZ9finPaR3a2rjsVBoDF4XREyRE4gazsfc/edit?usp=sharing

I'm matching the colleague and dates with the date in the Daily column to get their metrics using a FILTER formula. I'm at a loss in how to do that with an ArrayFormula so that I only need a single formula for each column. Any help would be appreciated.

As I'm still relatively new to the more complex uses of spreadsheets, please explain how any formulae you provide works.

Comment: Don't know if this is of any help. But if I were given this problem and given your bigger picture issues. I would aggregate all the main data into one tab and use Google's free Data Studio. My reason for using Data Studio, is that as you have found when looking at larger sets of data things become sluggish followed by users needing dynamic insights. The time spent learning Data Studio is well worth it, and giving the users the ability to filter the data as they need will impress them a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this time, access to Data Studio is restricted on our business accounts. It was definitely an option I was looking into, and may be an option for us in the distant future.

Comment: Accessing the URL u give of  ‘ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18rF3ZnvmNKZ9finPaR3a2rjsVBoDF4XREyRE4gazsfc/edit?usp=sharing ’ gives ‘Sorry, the file you have requested has been deleted.’. -Why? Q author, pls correct else explain, as w/o it, seems the Q is of little point.